# How to unbind an arbitrary listener in jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If there is some library (blackbox) that is putting a click listener on an `a` tag, that does something like do an alert in this case, it is also blocking the actual href navigation from working.

Is there a way in javascript/jquery to unbind that specific click listener and make the href clicking to work?

Note: I don't have the reference to the actual click function.

Thanks

Comment: add your own event listener as well. both (yours and library one) will fire

Comment: No. however, i guess you could remove and replace the anchor tag. the  new one of course won't have the listener.

Comment: Have you tried [capturing the event](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing#capturing) and stopping it's propagation toward the target. It won't unbind the event in the library, but it could help you achieve roughly the same thing. I haven't used it since my flash days, so I don't know exactly how much browser support it has. A quick google suggested it was supported since IE9 and stopPropagation works in both bubble and capture. However, I have not tested it so far.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
$(document).on('click','a',function(){$(this).preventDefault();console.log('a click'); return false;});
```

as a way to "disable" all present and yet to be generated `<a>` tags?

Comment: Just noticed, you do want the default action to take place. In that case my suggestion will not help you ;-)